# Trouble porting models from Blender to Ue4/Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, unreal-engine4

When I try to import the 3d models in the [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM1Pe.png) from Blender to Ue4/Unity, the models aren't rendered as intended, as shown in the [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T9ZT.jpg).
**The inside of the pot is rendered as transparent; 
half mask is rendered correctly, but instead of the other half, it's inside is rendered.**
**This happens with hollow models** (like glass bottles or pots), but I don't understand why the mask model does this too.
I think I'm doing something wrong while exporting the models from Blender, because in both Ue4 and Unity they are rendered as shown in the pic.
I would like to know why this happens and how I can fix it,
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the normals are inverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve.

1. In Blender, fix normal vector like this.
   https://all3dp.com/2/blender-recalculate-normals-simply-explained/
2. In Unity, Change material(shader) to draw double side like this
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-u3CEfgYhY

I recommend the first method.